# Why dose the "section size" in a WebAssembly binary module can not be calculated accurately?

Tags: webassembly

I found that the attribute "section size" shows in every "Section" is zero. Also there is a comment word "guess" written within a pair of brackets.

In the image Below:-

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emscripten produces the binary in one pass, hence it does not yet know section sizes when at the beginning of a section. So it writes zero first and later back-patches the value once the respective section is complete and its size known. You should see a line marked FIXUP later in the output that refers to the same byte offset.